# ¿Cómo puedo agregar cache a los elementos de mi sitio?

Tags: html5, cache, rendimiento, navegador-web, googlepagespeed

estoy rediseñando mi [sitio web](https://test.elgatodiego.com/) y en la pagina de PageSpeed de Google me dice que tengo 24 recuros que no tienen tiempo de vida en caché. [Pantalla de PageSpedd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNA9R.png). Investigando sobre el tema econtre que usando este tag:

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=31536000">`

Pero al volver hacer la validacion con PageSpeed me vuelven a mostrar los mismos elementos. ¿Cómo puedo darle un Tiempo de vida en caché a esos elementos?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que google No se refiere al cache de descarga de contenido.
Hay una API cache que proporciona los navegadores para que el sitio pueda verse en modo offline.
Podes ver aca un explicativo en español:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Recursos_offline_en_firefox
Consiste agregar un manifest al tag html.
Ejemplo:

```
<html manifest="ejemplo.appcache"> 
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, econtre esta guia http://fortheloveofseo.com/blog/performance/leverage-browser-caching-how-to-add-expires-headers/ y en el PageSpedd de Google ya aparece un tiempo de vide de 30 dias. El tema estaba en el .htaccess. GRACIAS

Comment: Gracias Diego por tu aporte. Creo que podes hacer algo asi tambien: header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60)));

Comment: Muchas Gracias.